# How can I change the background of Border-Control runtime in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have taken a Border Control in a WPF application. And I want to change the background on set focus. For that, the following code is written, but it is not working.

```
Style _Style = new System.Windows.Style(typeof(Border));
Trigger _Trigger = new Trigger();
_Trigger.Property = Border.IsFocusedProperty;
_Trigger.Value = true;
_Trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Green));
_Style.Triggers.Add(_Trigger);

Border1.Style = _Style;
```

Comment: That's what XAML is for, you know.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine with a XAML-defined style:

```
<Style x:Key="FocusBorder" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

....

<Border x:Name="MyBorder" Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource FocusBorder}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
```

And Code Behind:

```
Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyBorder.Focus();
}
```

By default Border is not `Focusable`, so you have to set `Focusable` to `true`.  And also keep in mind Keyboard Focus is restricted to Input Elements, of which a Border is not one.

Comment: Thank you for your kind suggestion. Your suggestion is worked, but have to replace one property IsKeyboardFocusWithin with IsFocused. Because there is some content within the border.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that you could (and almost certainly should) be doing this in XAML, the problem is twofold:

1. Borders aren't focusable by default.
2. You probably want `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`, not just `IsFocused`.

Comment: Thank you for your kind suggestion. Your suggestion is worked, but have to also set another property Focusable=true